# Comparing cardinality of set of real numbers $[2,3]$ and set of real numbers $[4,5]$

Tags: real-numbers, infinity, infinite-groups

The function $f(x) = x+2$ on the given sets $([2,3]$ and $[4,5])$ is bijective which should imply that the cardinality is equal.
Now, consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ on the sets of real numbers $[2,3]$ and $[4,9]$.
Again this function is bijective. This implies, the cardinality of $[2,3]$ is equal to $[4,9]$.

Since $[4,5]$ is a subset of $[4,9]$, therefore cardinality of $[4,5]$ is less than that of $[4,9]$ and therefore less than $[2,3]$.

But then this is in contradiction to our initial observation. What's the flaw in the above reasoning/comparison?

Comment: A set and proper subset can have the  same cardinality.

Comment: The flaw in you're argument is "since $[4,5]$ is a subset of $[4,9]$, therefore cardinality of $[4,5]$ is less than that of $[4,9]$". It should say "less or equal". 
For finite sets, it's true that if A is a proper subset of B then the cardinality of A is less than the cardinality of B but for infinite sets, a proper subset of a set can have the same cardinality of the set. As an example: the set of even numbers is a proper subset of the set of the natural numbers but they have the same cardinality (take the bijection $n \mapsto 2n$).

Comment: Isn’t it one of the definitions of infinity that a set of such cardinality must have a proper subset of the same cardinality?

Comment: @SBF It is a characterization : A set is infinite if and only if it is in bijection with one of its proper subsets.